# Unable using my device to run my application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, driver

I have Windows 7 32 bit and I'm trying to use a device to run my application , I installed the USB Driver adb for samsung captivate (that's my device) as in that [**link**](http://androidforums.com/samsung-captivate/123644-captivate-usb-drivers-links-here.html), it says install success, but after trying to run my application in my device, Eclipse doesn't recgonize my device(It is connected by USB).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check by giving command adb devices? does it say connected?

Comment: @nandeesh How am I able doing that?

Comment: @idish `adb devices` is a command-line utility.

Comment: @ThomasW Just done it, the list is empty.

Comment: maybe usb driver is not installed. Try Installing Samsung kies

Comment: @nandeesh Samsung kies doesn't recgonize my device ..

Comment: it might not recognize but it will have the driver

Comment: @nandeesh How can I install the driver without the kies recgonizing my device?

Comment: I meant, you should install [Samsung kies](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) even if it does not recognize your device. Install the drivers. Close Kies. Then try to connect phone. Wait for some time till computer shows that adb interface has been detected. Then give adb devices command

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether USB debugging is set in the phone.

In phone go to : Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine after installing the drivers? It is required in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

`adb`'s connection to the device is fickle. Try running these commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Sometimes it takes several tries before it can connect. (My experience is on OS X, Windows might be a bit different.)

Comment: Tried that, still list empty.

Comment: You may need to try it several times.

Comment: I just did now, I think there's problem with the driver itself.. what can I do about it?

Comment: I have the folder of the driver updated (after installation), Do I need to use that path anywhere?

Comment: @idish I don't have experience on Windows, but I don't think so.

Comment: When you connect the device does it display a notification that the USB cable has been attached for debugging?

Comment: Ah dammit.. Do you have any other suggestion for me? I'm struggling with it for 3 hours already.

Comment: I've also downloaded Samsung Kies software, but it doesn't detect my device also.. I can only reach the device files through "My computer"